# Get value of data-href attribute in xpath

Tags: xpath, attributes

Hello friends of the forum.

I want to get the value of the data-href attribute of a tag to

My code is the following:

```
<div id="myId">
    <h3>
        <a href="http//1.com"  data-href="http://domain1.com">Domain 1</a>
    </h3>
    <h3>
        <a href="http//2.com"  data-href="http://domain2.com">Domain 2</a>
    </h3>
        <h3>
        <a href="http//3.com"  data-href="http://domain3.com">Domain 3</a>
    </h3>
</div>
```

I tried the following way but I do not get results:

```
$entries = $xpath->query("//div[@id='myId']/h3"); 

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $node = $xpath->query("a/attribute::data-href", $entry);
    echo $node->item(0)->value."<br>";
}
```

How to show the result show:

```
http://domain1.com
http://domain2.com
http://domain3.com
```

Thank you very much for your future answers.

Comment: just use css locator: `#myId>h3>a`

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code :

```
$entries = $xpath->query("//div[@id='myId']/h3"); 

foreach ($entries as $entry) {

    $nodes = $xpath->query("a/attribute::data-href", $entry);
    foreach( $nodes as $node ) {
        echo $node->nodeValue."</br>";
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it does not work that way either.